# AndroidAsync - example of JSON sending and receiving

Tags: android, json

Recently, I have come across this very nice async http library:

https://github.com/koush/AndroidAsync

The problem is, that documentation on its github page is outdated and I am still too new to android, to find out from sources, how to perform these 2 basic actions (sending and receiving JSONs).

The only hint I found here, however its only receiving string, rather than json:

https://github.com/koush/AndroidAsync/issues/342

Sample of code would be highly helpful and appreciated, as couple of hours of tries and googling, didn't bring me any working solution

Comment: Why do you not start out with Android's `Asynctask`.

Comment: I agree with Jared, why not use the built in library, I personaly never use 3 party tools

Comment: Right after start, my app starts service, which at some point calls locationManager which in turn fired initially AsyncTask with http request (by Retrofit). The problem was, that I was not able neither to save the results form PostExecute onto db (using separate SQLOpenHelper class nor directly), nor pass them back to onStart function of the service using intents.

Comment: ... Then at some point I found AndroidAsync which let me receive at least a string right from the place where saving to db was not a problem. Additionally it does not require to create separate pojo class which in my case was redundant